# Error 1004 - Opening and activating workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have some issues while trying to copy/paste data between workbooks. I need to extract data from two different workbooks (A & B) to put it in a third one.
Since A & B have the exact same structure, I use the same code for both of them. However it works for A and I've got an error 1004 for B.

It seems that it happens when you do not specify the parent workbook/worksheet properly but I don't think this is the issue here since the code works for A.

If someone has an insight on this matter, I'm all ears!

Thank you for your help!

CH

```
    Sub Data_Extraction()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wba As Workbook, wbb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wba= Workbooks.Open("D:\xxx\A.xlsx")
    Set wbb= Workbooks.Open("D:\xxx\B.xlsx")

    Dim wsa As Worksheet, wsb As Worksheet
    Set wsa = wb.Worksheets("a")
    Set wsb = wb.Worksheets("b")

   'I use a named variable here 
    X = Range("X")

    If X=2 Then

        ''We fill the tab a''
        For i = 9 To 400
           wba.Activate
           If wba.Worksheets("a").Cells(i, 2).Value = 5 Then
               wba.Worksheets("a").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 8)).Copy
               wb.Activate
               wsa.Range(Cells(7, 2), Cells(7, 9)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
               wsa.Range("B7").EntireRow.Insert
           End If
        Next i

        ''We fill the tab b''
        For i = 9 To 400
           wbb.Activate
           If wbb.Worksheets("b").Cells(i, 2).Value = 5 Then
               wbb.Worksheets("b").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 8)).Copy
               wb.Activate
               wsb.Range(Cells(7, 2), Cells(7, 9)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
               wsb.Range("B7").EntireRow.Insert
           End If
        Next i

    End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: I think it might be because of `X`, try defining the workbook for it as well. For example `X = wsa.Range("X")`

Comment: After modification, the problem persists.
Thank you though!

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Everything works fine until
`wbb.Worksheets("b").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 8)).Copy`.
What is strange is that it works for A.

Comment: And you are sure that there are no protected/hidden cells that you are trying to copy (should not cause an issue), and that you have let VBA open the 2 workbooks each time?

Comment: No protected, no hidden cells and VBA opens the 2 workbooks each time.
After some tests, I also know that this line is correct: `If wbb.Worksheets("b").Cells(i, 2).Value = 5 Then` because I can display check messages when the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: You mean when the condition is not fulfilled? I am kind of stumped actually. see what you get when you run `debug.print wbb.Worksheets("b").Cells(i, 2).Value` See if its referencing what you expect it to

Comment: My previous test was similar and I indeed got what I expected with the `debug.print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lots of cases when you use Excel methods like protect/unprotect copy/paste, you should try to mimick as close as possible the configuration Excel would be in when a user would go through those steps, if you step away from that you are likely to wind up with instability cropping up in generic error codes as 5 and 1004.

In this case I believe you should do

```
wbb.Worksheets("b").Activate
```

*before* you start a copy from worksheet("b").

Comment: It looks like it is indeed a problem from the Copy method.

I solved the problem by coding differently what I wanted to do.

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I was also going to say, try sourcerange.copy(destinationrange) which works more outside the userinterface or do Application.CutCopyMode = 0 before switching workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is not that you didn't activate the sheet (though that does work, it's not a good solution)

```
wbb.Worksheets("b").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 8)).Copy
```

Here the `Cells()` calls (unlike the `Range()` call) are not qualified by any worksheet object, so they will default to the ActiveSheet. In a regular module this is equivalent to writing:

```
wbb.Worksheets("b").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 8)).Copy
```

...and is prone to failure when the active sheet is not what you expect.

This is robust and doesn't require you to activate a specific worksheet:

```
With wbb.Worksheets("b")
     .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 8)).Copy
End With
```